# Compute all possible value of a complex number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers

Let C be the set of complex numbers and j the imaginary unit. Compute all possible values of ((1 + $((1 + \sqrt{-3})^3 \times (1-j)^2)^\frac13 + j$

So, i tried doing the 2 ways,

1)
= (1+$\sqrt3j) \times (1-j)^\frac23 + j$

$ = 2e^{j\frac\pi3} \times$ (roots of the $(1-j)^\frac23 $ which are $\sqrt[3]2e^{j-\frac\pi6},\sqrt[3]2e^{j\frac\pi2},\sqrt[3]2e^{j\frac{7\pi}6}$) + j

= $\therefore 2^\frac43e^\frac\pi6 + j,2^\frac43e^\frac{5\pi}6 + j,2^\frac43e^\frac{3\pi}2 + j$

2)= (($2e^{j\frac\pi3})^3 \times (\sqrt2e^{-j\frac\pi4})^2)^\frac13 + j

$= (16e^{j\frac\pi2})^\frac13 + j$, then I will compute the roots for this equation.

May I know which method is right or what should be the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: Note that there are also two possible square roots of $-3$.

Answer (score 0):

$$((1 + ((1 + \sqrt{-3})^3 \times (1-i)^2)^\frac13 + i=$$

$$1+i+\left(\left((1+\sqrt{-3})^3(1-i)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)=$$

$$(1+i)+\left(\left(-2i(1+i\sqrt{3})^3\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)=$$

$$\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{1}{4}\pi i}+\left(\left(2e^{-\frac{1}{2}\pi i}(2e^{\frac{1}{3}\pi i})^3\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)=$$

$$\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{1}{4}\pi i}+\left(16e^{\frac{1}{2}\pi i}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}=$$

$$\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{1}{4}\pi i}+2\left(2\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}e^{\frac{1}{6}\pi i}=$$

$$(1+i)+\left(2\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\left(\sqrt{3}+i\right)$$